# how to optimize the isPresent code in java

Tags: java

this is the condition statement, can it use ifPresent to replace it?：

```
if (mo.findParameterValueByPath("primaryCRLDP").isPresent() 
    && mo.findParameterValueByPath("secondaryCRLDP").isPresent() 
&& mo.findParameterValueByPath("primaryCRLDP").get().equals(mo.findParameterValueByPath("secondaryCRLDP").get())) {
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Probably such code is one of the reasons why the people who gave us optionals tell us to mainly use them as parameters to methods, not as return type

Comment: @GhostCat Saw that edit fail ;)

Comment: Yep, mobile phone isn't the ideal device for such activities...

Answer (score 2):

`Optional<T>#ifPresent` takes a `Consumer<? super T>` as a parameter and returns nothing, so you won't be able to use it to "optimize" the code above.  Honestly, there isn't much you can do besides storing each `Optional<T>` in a variable so you aren't required to call `findParameterValueByPath` twice for each:

```
Optional<T> o1 = mo.findParameterValueByPath("primaryCRLDP");
Optional<T> o2 = mo.findParameterValueByPath("secondaryCRLDP");

return o1.isPresent() && o2.isPresent() && o1.get().equals(o2.get());
```

You didn't specify what generic type the `Optional<T>` uses, so I left it generic in the example above.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks!  I'd say there isn't much more that can be done, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Actually, since [Optionals compare their contents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), the return statement can just be `return o1.equals(o2);`.

Comment: @VGR The one downside to that is that two `Optional`s are equal if `both instances have no value present`.  The OP first checks if both values are present, so I'm not sure that would be the best choice in this scenario.  I never knew about that though, thanks!

Comment: @danny You're welcome! If your problem is solved, feel free to upvote/accept this answer by clicking on the green tick to the left side of the post.